# Remove an element from Set Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, set

```
static final List<String> allowedType = asList(type1,type2);

Set<String> set1 = serviceClass.getType()
                               .stream()
                               .filter(type -> allowedType.contains(type))
                               .collect(toSet());
```

The requirement consists of two-part,

part1. if the types received from serviceClass has any of the service type mentioned in allowedType, add it to set1.

part 2 .After the above operation, i need to check if set1 contains both the types, if yes, one type needs to be removed .

Part1 is straightforward, as of now i have implemented part2 using

```
if (set1.contains("type1" && set1.contains("typep2") {
    set1.remove("type");
}
```

Is there anyway part1 and 2 can be clubbed into a single operation ?

Thanks,

Comment: *Is there anyway part1 and 2 can be clubbed into a single piece* what is this even supposed to mean?

Comment: i mean after getting Set<String> set1 = serviceClass.getType().stream().filter(type -> allowedType.contains(type)).collect(toSet());, instead of  seperate check, can it be done in a single line

Comment: you might want to show some example - as this is kind of un-clear

Comment: @Eugene, hope it is more clear now

Comment: Have you considered moving your data into a map<string,List<ServiceType>>, with the key being the result of the `getType()` ?  then you can just check if the map has keys you're interested in, and can build a set containing arbitrary types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are always two types and you can always keep at most one of them, you may use `limit`:

```
    Set<String> set1 = serviceClass.getType()
           .stream()
           .filter(type -> allowedType.contains(type))
           .limit(1)
           .collect(toSet());
```

`limit(1)` will return a stream of 1 element if at least one element passes the filter, otherwise the empty stream. It seems to me that this will give you what you asked for (not tested).

Comment: Alternatively to `.limit(1) .collect(toSet())` you can use `.findFirst() .map(Collections::singleton) .orElse(Collections.emptySet())`, if space-efficiency of the result matters…